# Write a program to sum first 10 natural numbers using a "for loop"

Tags: c

I am having difficulty solving this question by using for loop (I am a beginner).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int a = 0, sum = 0;
    for(a=0;a<=10;sum+=a)
    {
        a++;
    }
    printf("The sum of no. from 1 to 10 is--->>%d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile this program?  What output did it give?  What output did you expect?  Could you post the full code, including all the directives at the top of the file?

Comment: It looks like it does what you expect. Do you need help _compiling_ and _linking_ it?

Comment: @Neil OP's code gives 66; correct answer is 55.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter, the natural numbers start at 1, so your for loop should be 1 to 10, not 0 to 10.

Comment: Carl Gauss says not to use a loop for this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that you're adding `a` to `sum` at the end of each loop (in the *iteration-statement*, or the third part of the `for` statement). Thus, at the **end** of the last loop that you *want* to run, `a` will be `11` – but you add that to `sum` *before* the next `a <= 10` comparison is made, preventing further iterations. So, your answer is `11` to high.

This confusion arises primarily because of your unconventional placements of the `sum += a` and `a++` statements. Normally, in a `for` loop, you would have the iteration/increment expression (`a++`, in your case) in the `for` statement and the *action* that you want to occur each time (`sum += a`) *inside* the loop.

Thus, a slight rearrangement to the code, as follows, will solve your issue:

```c
int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++) { // Start at a = 1 because adding zero is pointless!
        sum += a;
    }
    printf("The sum of no. from 1 to 10 is--->>%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```